# Python giving this error message when retrieving data from CSV file: "unhashable type: 'Series' "

Tags: python, pandas, csv, statistics

So I'm importing and reading a CSV (Excel) file to gather the mean and standard deviation of certain criteria.Here is the code that I've generated to open it and read it as well as it's corresponding shape.

```
data=pd.read_csv("Factors_Monthly.csv")
shape_data=(data.shape)
print("Data Shape:",shape_data)
```

I want to find the average monthly market excess rate since the year 2000 (from 2000-01 till the end of the sample). The shape of the data is (1119, 6). When generating a code to find this monthly rate which is :

```
monthly_rate=data.loc((data['year']>=2000).iloc[200001:]) #this is choosing years from 2000 and ahead
s2= statistics.mean(monthly_rate['mktrf']) #this is taking the mean of the column mktrf in the excel file
print(s2)
```

I get the error  " unhashable type: 'Series' " and it's corresponding traceback is:
[image]

EDIT:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a sample of data using `data.head(10).to_dict()`?

Comment: Where would I insert this code?

Comment: Insert the output of that into your post. So we can see what your data looks like. Also what is `d`?

Comment: Added the output and fixed the error with "d"

Comment: maybe you should use `[ ]` instead of `()` in `.loc[]`. And I'm not sure if you can use `.iloc[]` inside `.loc[]` - maybe it should be `.loc[..].iloc[...]`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the `statistics` module. `pandas` has its own `mean` function. Try:

```
average = data.loc[data["year"].ge(2000),"mktrf"].mean()
```